# Write own assert Function with expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I would like to create my own `Assert` method similar to the code below, but it is not working.

```c#
// Method Usage
Argument.Assert(() => Measurements.Count > 0);

// Method Implementation
public static void Assert(Expression<bool> expression)
{
  bool value = expression.Compile();
  if(!value)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Assert: " + expression.ToString() + " may not be false!");
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? The error is: `'Error   1   Cannot convert lambda to an expression tree whose type argument 'bool' is not a delegate type'`.

First I had `Expression<Func<bool>> expression` and `expression.Compile()()` but this always crashed with `TargetInvocationException`.

Comment: Well show what that `TargetInvocationException` showed - using `Expression<Func<bool>>` is certainly more appropriate than `Expression<bool>` which is effectively invalid... (`Expression<T>` is only valid when `T` is a delegate type.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Expression<bool>` is invalid as T must be a delegate type.
`Expression<Func<bool>>` is valid, although I'm not sure why you prefer that over a simple `Func<bool>`. That's your call.

This should work

```
public static void Assert(Expression<Func<bool>> expression)
{
    if (!expression.Compile().Invoke())
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Assert: {0} may not be false!", expression.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I wan't to log things here, and I also need to use the Stuff in release build - and i wan't to have control over the output. Anyway, thanks, works great.

Comment: That's cool, I figured there would be more to it. I did notice that you're printing the expression into the exception message. I don't think `expression.ToString()` will print much more than `() => False`. `expression.Body.ToString()` may give you more, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
public static void Assert(Expression<Func<bool>> expression)
{
    if (!expression.Compile().Invoke())
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Assert: " + expression.ToString() + " may not be false!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should one use an `Expression` if a simple `Delegate` works fine? :)

Comment: Thanks, this is at least working but the output looks like: `Assert: System.Func`1[System.Boolean] may not be false`

Comment: I'm trying to fix it... give me a few

Comment: use: `public static void Assert(Expression<Func<bool>> expression)` ... `if(!expression.Compile()())`

Comment: @SirBirne yeah i was at that point... but im sure you rather want "Measurement.Count > 0" right?

Comment: @SirBirne i can give you the name of the method and the linenumber but the body of the delegate is a tough nut =(